# Android studio execute AsyncClass before onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I have this code where i have to call data from database yung asynctask the coordinates for my googlemap. but the `onMapReady` is executing before my Asynctask so the location is always null. I call the asynctask on my oncreate here is my code.

#### AsyncTask on onCreate

```
        HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<>();
        postData.put("rqstID", rqstID);
        AsyncClass taskDetails = new AsyncClass(AcceptActivity.this, postData, "Getting details", new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d("AcceptActivity", s);
                JSONObject parentObject = null;
                try {
                    parentObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    lat1 = finalObject.getString("rqstLat");
                    lng1 = finalObject.getString("rqstLng");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        taskDetails.execute("http://10.0.2.2/wingman/requestDetails.php");
```

#### onMapReady

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat1), Double.valueOf(lng1));
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(location)
            .snippet("I'm around here!!!");
    CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions()
            .center(location)
            .radius(2000)
            .fillColor(0x55add8e6)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            .strokeWidth(2);
    mGoogleMap.addCircle(circle);
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that your async task could complete before the Google map's `onMapReady()` were called.  Instead, I propose that you make the REST call for map information from the `onMapReady()` method itself.  This way, you can be sure that when the callback is fired, there is an actual live Google map handle to which you could assign a marker etc.

Here is a skeleton of what the code might look like:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    new YourAsyncTask(this).execute();
}
```

Then in your async task you can parse the data and assign the marker to your Google Map.

Comment: That is the problem before callback is fired `onMapReady()` is already done and looking for coordinates since `Asynctask` is not yet done location is still null.

Comment: @J.Deep The async call for the map should be made when the map is ready, I think you missed the point of my answer.

Comment: Okay okay. I gotchu, i'll try it now. :)

Comment: If that async call is doing other stuff for the activity, then you might need to make multiple REST calls.  Well the Google map will be doing this already, so one additional small async call probably won't ruin the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make a function for what ever task you want to perform on map basis on user experience and pass parameter related which value you need to perform your task on map like latitude longitude.

```
private void yourFunctionName(double lat1, double lng1){
   LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat1), Double.valueOf(lng1));
   CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15);
   mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
   MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(location)
        .snippet("I'm around here!!!");
   CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions()
        .center(location)
        .radius(2000)
        .fillColor(0x55add8e6)
        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
        .strokeWidth(2);
   mGoogleMap.addCircle(circle);
   mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

you not need to perform any task in onMapReady() function

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mGoogleMap = googleMap;

}
```

store only google map object

```
mGoogleMap = googleMap;
```

now perform network operation and call which function you want to perform

```
  HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<>();
    postData.put("rqstID", rqstID);
    AsyncClass taskDetails = new AsyncClass(AcceptActivity.this, postData, 
    "Getting details", new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            Log.d("AcceptActivity", s);
            JSONObject parentObject = null;
            try {
                parentObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("result");
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
                lat1 = finalObject.getString("rqstLat");
                lng1 = finalObject.getString("rqstLng");
                yourFunctionName(Lat1, lng1) // CALL THIS AFTER GETED RESULT
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    taskDetails.execute("http://10.0.2.2/wingman/requestDetails.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Async in onMapReady() won't help, instead replace somefragment.getMapAsync(this) with your Async task call and add somefragment.getMapAsync(this) in the end of onPostExecute.